# .NET and ODP.NET data retrieval

Tags: .net, sql, vb.net, oracle

I'm working on a really simple web service and hoping to get some help. I took the stock web service from Visual Studio, and started modifying it with very limited knowledge of ODP.NET.

Effectively, what I'm trying to do is bring back a set of results from a SQL Query that has a variable in it that I pass to the service. WR_Premise is the variable that I'd like to incorporate, after I get my query working correctly. I call my function using the WCF Test client, but am getting a `InvalidOperationException` when I try to run the following code.

```
Public Function GetData(ByVal value As Integer) As String Implements IService1.GetData
        Dim wrpremise As Integer
        Dim state As String
        Dim queryString As String = _
         "select MV_OUTAGE_DURATION.CAUSE_DESC, MV_OUTAGE_DURATION.DEV_NAME, MV_OUTAGE_DURATION.DEV_TYPE_NAME, MV_OUTAGE_DURATION.EVENTNUM, MV_OUTAGE_DURATION.OUT_MINUTES, MV_OUTAGE_DURATION.OFF_DTS , MV_OUTAGE_DURATION.RESTORE_DTS , MV_OUTAGE_DURATION.SYS_RESP_TYPE from MV_we_outage_premise, MV_OUTAGE_DURATION where mv_we_outage_premise.evntnum = MV_OUTAGE_DURATION.eventnum and mv_we_outage_premise.we_premise = '995184' order by(MV_OUTAGE_DURATION.RESTORE_DTS)"
        Dim command As New OracleCommand(queryString)

    value = wrpremise

    Dim oradb As String = "Data Source=****;User Id=******;Password=***********;"
    Dim conn As New OracleConnection(oradb)
    conn.Open()
    state = conn.State.ToString()

    command.ExecuteNonQuery()

    MsgBox(state)
    conn.Close()
    state = conn.State.ToString()
    MsgBox(state)

    Return String.Format("You entered: {0}", value)
End Function
```

I can get the service to work and return the states when I take the `command.ExecuteNonQuery()` out of the service, but that doesn't help me out much... 
Also, anyone know an easy way to output the results to XML?

Comment: Why would you ExecuteNonQuery when you're in fact executing a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems in your query

- First, the command is not associated to the connection
- Second, you are retrieving records, so your should use a DataReader
  or a DataAdapter to fill a DataTable

For the command connection use

```
    command.Connection = conn
```

For the retrieving records

```
    Dim reader as OracleDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        ... use your data         
    }
```

See here a reference on a [OracleDataReader](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/OracleDataReaderClass.htm) and here for a [OraclaDataAdapter](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/OracleDataAdapterClass.htm)